# Connection was broken with jenkins agent using WinSW

Tags: jenkins, windows-services, agent

My agent is connected since 1 week through winSW (https://github.com/winsw/winsw) running the jenkins agent as a service and now I'm getting this error and the agent is not restarting

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at jenkins.agents.WebSocketAgents$Session.closed(WebSocketAgents.java:141)
    at jenkins.websocket.WebSocketSession.onWebSocketSomething(WebSocketSession.java:91)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.onWebSocketClose(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onClose(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.callApplicationOnClose(WebSocketSession.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.disconnect(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.DisconnectCallback.succeeded(DisconnectCallback.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection$CallbackBridge.writeSuccess(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.notifyCallbackSuccess(FrameFlusher.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.succeedEntries(FrameFlusher.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.succeeded(FrameFlusher.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.flush(FrameFlusher.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.process(FrameFlusher.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.outgoingFrame(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.close(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

But in the service setup I mention to restart if error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBmFF.png)

any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some R&D, I found that due to some Network Policies of my company It cuts the connection after some time...
The solution for me was to create a script that runs every 10 mins to check if the agent is offline or not, so it'll relaunch the agent (no more time out)